# Can I Use Variables from One Method to another?

Tags: c#, excel

Can I use a declared variable or a instance of an object from one method to another?

```
private void OnBrowseFileClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string path = null;
            path = OpenFile();
        }

private string OpenFile()
        {
            string path = null;
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Title = "Open source file";
            fileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            fileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            fileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            fileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            Nullable<bool> result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {
                path = fileDialog.FileName;
            }

            textBox1.Text = path;
            return path;
        }
```

Now, I want to get that path and write it on excel. how will I do this, please help, I am week old in using C#.

```
private void btnCreateReport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = "sample.xls"; //Dummy Data
            string functionName = "functionName"; //Dummy Data
            string path = null;

            AnalyzerCore.ViewModel.ReportGeneratorVM reportGeneratorVM = new AnalyzerCore.ViewModel.ReportGeneratorVM();
            reportGeneratorVM.ReportGenerator(filename, functionName, path);
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an instance field to store the value of your variable.

Like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // New instance field
    private string _path = null;

    private void OnBrowseFileClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Notice the use of the instance field
        _path = OpenFile(); 
    }

    // OpenFile implementation here...

    private void btnCreateReport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "st_NodataSet.xls"; //Dummy Data
        string functionName = "functionName"; //Dummy Data

        AnalyzerCore.ViewModel.ReportGeneratorVM reportGeneratorVM = new AnalyzerCore.ViewModel.ReportGeneratorVM();
        // Reuse the instance field here
        reportGeneratorVM.ReportGenerator(filename, functionName, _path); 
    }
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173118.aspx) is a link which describes fields in much more detail than what I could.

Comment: Thank You Lukazoid... It answered my inquiry. :D

Comment: Hi, is it possible to store a function with return in a string and call it in a method?
Example is:
public string func = @"public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            int z;
            if ((x == 10) || (y == 20))
            {
                z = x + y;
            }
            else
            {
                z = x;
            }

            return z;
        }";

And I want to call and execute this function in a method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move the `string path` as a member inside your class, and remove the declaration inside the methods. that should do it

Answer (score 0):

Use string path as a class level variable.

Use static private string path if you want to use it between pages.

Use private string path if you only need to use it on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

you must define the variable as field in your class:

```
Private string path = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

use `static private string path;`